# Using toLabel in Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, localization

I am trying to use the following SOQL query in Data Loader expecting to receive a translated Status value:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, toLabel(Status), CreatedDate FROM Task ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5
```

It does not return any value for that column for this query.

Is there a way to get a translated picklist value in Data Loader?

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this to the Salesforce developer forums and there I found that there's an idea on the IdeaExchange to address this same issue, which suggests that it's not possible.

Question on developer forum:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BWJg

Idea on IdeaExchange:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l63zAAA